# Is this as issue in Gitlab API for searching issue or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: api, gitlab, gitlab-api

I created an issue with the name `newissue`. On searching it using this API `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/search?scope=issues&search=newissue` ([source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/search.html#scope-issues)) through Postman, I am not able to see my issue. Even when I log out from my account, the issue is not visible from the Gitlab search bar. Do I need to do some changes in the project to make issues visible globally? (Note: Project is already public). The same case is happening in the project search API ([source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/search.html#scope-projects)).

[with filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc7XI.png)
[without filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBVBE.png)

Comment: You might want to add what issue did you add if it's public, the API call that you're making

Comment: Let's say I created an issue https://gitlab.com/ayushthakur281999/test-project/-/issues/1. It will not be visible if I remove the filter from the search bar. You can refer to the images updated in the post.